# Get the ID of the page a menu item links to?

Tags: functions, menus, pages

I am currently using a custom walker to customize the output of `wp_nav_menu()`, and I am trying to add additional information to the `<a>` tags.

What I want the output for each menu link to look like is:

```
<a class="boxPAGEID" href="#">About Me Page</a>
```

Where `PAGEID` is the ID of the page I'm linking to.

The reason is because I am developing a theme that opens page content in lightboxes, which are triggered by the class in the  tag.

Below is the code of the custom walker in my `functions.php` file (after the code I'll point to the area where I'm having trouble):

```
class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{

      function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
      {
           global $wp_query;     
           $pageid = $wp_query->post->ID;

           $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

           $class_names = $value = '';

           $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

           $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
           $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

           $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'>';

           $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
           $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . '#' .'"' : '';

           $prepend = '<strong>';
           $append = '</strong>';
           $description  = ! empty( $item->description ) ? '<span>'.esc_attr( $item->description ).'</span>' : '';

           if($depth != 0)
           {
                     $description = $append = $prepend = "";
           }

            $item_output = $args->before;
            $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes . 'class="box' . $pageid . '"' .'>';
            $item_output .= $args->link_before .$prepend.apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ).$append;
            $item_output .= $args->link_after;
            $item_output .= '</a>';
            $item_output .= $args->after;

            $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );

            if ($item->menu_order == 1) {
                $classes[] = 'first';
            }

            }
}
```

Towards the end are a couple of lines that begin with `$item_output`. The second line is where I'm trying to generate the page ID:

```
$item_output .= '<a'. $attributes . 'class="box' . $pageid . '"' .'>';
```

Where `$pageid` is according to:

```
global $wp_query;    
$pageid = $wp_query->post->ID;
```

This gives me a single, fixed ID for all the links generated.

Alternatively, instead of `$pageid` I tried using `$item->ID`, but that gave me the ID of the menu item instead.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If there are alternatives to the page id, that would work, too. I initially tried using $item->url, but the url wouldn't function as a class name. The page title works only if there are no spaces, and the other attributes are not generated by default.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The page ID (or object ID, since a menu item can link to any object) is stored in the `postmeta` table, with the key `_menu_item_object_id`. So you can get the page ID with the following code:

```
get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
```

Comment: JAN!!!!! This did it! Sorry for the late response, but your suggestion did the trick! You're fabulous! Thank you!

And for the record for those who aren't sure what to do:

I changed the `$pageid = $wp_query->post->ID;` at the top of the page to `$pageid = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );`

Comment: @Jan Fabry : Superb!!! it save my time..Great!!!

Answer (score 1):

The `PAGEID` is available in `$item->object_id`, if `$item->object` is `page`.

`$item->object` contains the type of the menu item. Possible values are `page`,`post`,`category`,...

`$item->object_id` contains the ID for the object.

I found out this by `var_dump($item)` on WordPress 5.4.2.

Comment: This shall be the accepted answer as it is more performant than the get_post_meta approach.

Answer (score -1):

I could not look at your code deeply but for creating menu maybe you should use get_pages..

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

```
<?php 
  $pages = get_pages(); 
  foreach ($pages as $pagg) {
    $option = '<a class="box' . $pagg->ID . '" href="#">';
    $option .= $pagg->post_title;
    $option .= '</a>';
    echo $option;
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Serdar! Unfortunately this won't work because I need the menu to be able to be controlled from the appearance > menu section of the admin panel! That's why I'm using wp_menu_nav and not get_pages.