# Setting color of specific menu items depending on page or post tag

Tags: menus, tags

I have a website that uses a plugin that lets me add categories and tags to pages.

Is there a way of automatically changing the color of a menu item linked to all pages with a particular tag or category?

Specifically,  I want to add the class "unwatched" to the menu item of any page that has been tagged with the "unwatched" tag.

I have tried the following code but I'm sure I've got it wrong: (it didn't work)

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class', 'custom_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 2 );

function custom_nav_menu_css_class( $classes, $item ) {
    if( 'tag' === $item->object ){
        array_push( $classes, 'unwatched' ); 
    }
    return $classes;    
}
```

Comment: It is probably a duplicate question. Here is the answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/109270/9821

Comment: I don't want to have to manually add a class to individual menu items though; I'd like it to be done dynamically, depending on what categories or tags the page has

Comment: You may still use the code I referred to. Change the conditional statement to check with your taxonomy conditionally and add the CSS class to your menu item. Then use that class in CSS. If this is not enough then share what you have done till now. Without reference, no one would be able to help you.

Comment: Yes, I want to "Change the conditional statement to check with your taxonomy conditionally and add the CSS class to your menu item" - I want to add the class "unwatched" to the menu item of any page that has been tagged with the "unwatched" tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, got it :-)

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_nav_menu_item_class' );

function add_nav_menu_item_class( $items ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $post_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );
        $post_tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );
        if ( $post_tags ) {
            foreach( $post_tags as $tag ) {
                if  ( $tag->name == 'unwatched' ) {
                    $item->classes[] = 'unwatched';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

The associated CSS, which changes the color of all menu items tagged with the 'unwatched' class, is

```
li.unwatched > a {
    color: FORESTGREEN;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `array_push()` try using `$item->classes[] = 'unwatched';`

Although the more I look at it, where is your code checking if the tag is 'unwatched'?

You're pushing 'unwatched' into the classes array but your tag check isn't referencing it?

Is there more code that's not displayed here?

**UPDATE**
Looking at your second effort I think I understand where the issue is... ...when a page is loaded you're checking to see if the tag is present for the page that is loaded by using 'get_the_tags()', you're not checking if all of the pages associated with the menu items have that tag. Since the result returns TRUE for that page, then the *foreach* adds the class to each.

What you need to do is, in the *foreach*, check the tags for each specific page/post ID and then add the class dependent on that.  So within the *foreach* you'd need `get_the_tags( $item->ID )`. May need more work than just that to ensure you're getting the ID of each item, but I think that's the right way to go about doing applying the class.

Comment: That's all I have for now, but I'll have another go.

Comment: Re **UPDATE**: Something not right here. `$post_tags = get_the_tags( $item->ID );` doesn't return anything. `$post_tags = get_the_tags( );` returns all the tags of the post currently being displayed. 

I need the tags of each menu item's associated post but I can't figure out how to do that :-(

Comment: I'm wondering if I need o create a Custom Walker for wp_nav_menu() e.g. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu

Comment: I don't think so... ...if `get_tags( $item->ID )` isn't returning anything then it may not be properly pulling the ID.  Can you set the IDs into a variable first and ensure that it is getting IDs.  To test you could try just hardcoding an ID that you know has the tag and var_dump the results to confirm.

Comment: You're right, @Tony Djukic, the line I need is `$post_id = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );` (from https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/13604/get-the-id-of-the-page-a-menu-item-links-to) Thanks :-)

Comment: Fantastic, glad you got it sorted.  If you have time post your full solution after so anyone else looking to do something similar can reference it.  :-)

Comment: The full solution is my last post - the one entitled "OK, got it". Do I need to / can I flag it, somehow?

Comment: You selected it as the accepted answer, that should do it.  I upvoted it as well.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

My next effort:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_nav_menu_item_class' );

function add_nav_menu_item_class( $items ) {
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $post_tags = get_the_tags();
        if ( $post_tags ) {
            foreach( $post_tags as $tag ) {
                if  ( $tag->name == 'unwatched' ) {
                    $item->classes[] = 'unwatched';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
```

This has an interesting effect - if the page I'm looking at has the 'unwatched' tag, ALL my menu items have the 'unwatched' class; conversely, if the page I'm looking at doesn't have the 'unwatched' tag, NONE of my menu items have the 'unwatched' class.

Maybe it's not possible to achieve this, but what I want is for the 'unwatched' class to be on every menu item linked to a page that has the 'unwatched' tag, and none of the others, regardless of which page I'm currently looking at.